# Use of Grobner Basis to Compute Relations with respect to Quotient Polynomial Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, groebner-basis

I think I might have phrased the question poorly, but I have a somewhat basic question about how to use Grobner bases in a particular example. Suppose I have some algebra
$$R=\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2^3,x_3^3,x_1x_2],$$
and the surjective map of $R$-modules
$$ R\oplus R\rightarrow R\cdot x_2+R\cdot x_3^2,$$
where $e_1=(1,0)\mapsto x_2$ and $e_2=(0,1)\mapsto x_3$.
Is there a way to systematically determine the kernel of the map? For example, I know that $(-x_3^3)\cdot x_2+(x_2x_3)\cdot x_3^2=0$, but is there a way to get all such relations?

Comment: See Schreyers theorem in chapter fifteen of Eisenbud.